# DB2 table's UNIQUE INDEX not showing in TABCONST and CONSTDEP tables

Tags: sql, db2, database-metadata, system-tables, rapidsql

I am trying to query the unique indices from `SYSCAT` tables for some user tables using the query below which uses 4 catalog tables (`INDEXES`, `INDEXCOLUSE`, `TABCONST`, `CONSTDEP`). I realized all indices are there in `INDEXES` and `INDEXCOLUSE` tables but many of them are missing in `TABCONST` and `CONSTDEP` tables.

Is there any reason for having data missing in `TABCONST` and `CONSTDEP` tables? Is there some procedure to refresh the data from those catalog tables?

```
SELECT
    T.TABSCHEMA AS TABLE_SCHEMA,
    T.TABNAME AS TABLE_NAME,
    CASE T.TYPE
        WHEN 'F' THEN 'Foreign Key'
        WHEN 'I' THEN 'Functional Dependency'
        WHEN 'K' THEN 'Check'
        WHEN 'P' THEN 'Primary Key'
        WHEN 'U' THEN 'Unique'
    END AS TYPE,
    I.INDSCHEMA AS INDEX_SCHEMA,
    I.INDNAME AS INDEX_NAME,
    U.COLNAME AS COLUMN_NAME,
    U.COLSEQ AS COLUMN_ORDINAL,
    CASE U.COLORDER
        WHEN 'A' THEN 'Ascending'
        WHEN 'D' THEN 'Descending'
        WHEN 'I' THEN 'Included (unordered)'
    END AS COLUMN_SORRING
FROM
    SYSCAT.TABCONST T
    INNER JOIN
    SYSCAT.CONSTDEP C
    ON T.CONSTNAME = C.CONSTNAME
    INNER JOIN
    SYSCAT.INDEXES I
    ON
        C.BSCHEMA = I.INDSCHEMA AND
        C.BNAME = I.INDNAME
    INNER JOIN
    SYSCAT.INDEXCOLUSE U
    ON
        I.INDSCHEMA = U.INDSCHEMA AND
        I.INDNAME = U.INDNAME
WHERE
    TRIM(UPPER(T.TABSCHEMA)) = 'MYSCHEMA' AND
    TRIM(UPPER(T.TABNAME)) = 'MYTABLE'AND
    C.BTYPE = 'I'
--INDICES ONLY
ORDER BY
    T.TABSCHEMA,
    T.TABNAME,
    I.INDSCHEMA,
    I.INDNAME
;
```

### Notes

Edited question's title: Forgot to mention this is all about UNIQUE index instead of just index!

Comment: The main tables should be syscat.indexes/indexcoluse, and then left join to syscat.tabconst/constdep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an index directly it is not a constraint:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX myindex on mytab(mycol)
```

However, if you create or alter a table and use `UNIQUE` to declare a single column or several as such, then it is a constraint.

Comment: thanks much, I just assumed that unique indices and constraints would be always interchangeable (just for practical reasons) so incorrectly expected to find the metadata in all 4 tables. This [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/147/106269) has interesting items.